# One-way ArcGIS replication copying __ATTACH tables instead of base tables

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, sql-server, replication

I'm trying to get one-way replication working in ESRI ArcGIS 10.  Here's a quick summary of the steps I followed:

1. Open map in ArcMap with the relevant data layers I want to replicate
2. Choose Create Replica from distribution toolbar
3. Choose One-Way Replica, Parent-to-Child
4. Use Simple Model (as opposed to Full Model)

This works for me with one problem.  Several of the featuresets that the data layers are based  off of have __ATTACH tables.  When I perform the replication, the __ATTACH tables get replicated but the base tables do not.

For example, there is a layer based on a featureset called Parcels that may have attachments stored in a SQL Server table called Parcels_*ATTACH.  In the replicated copy of the geodatabase, there is a Parcels*_ATTACH table but no Parcels table.

If it makes any difference, the Parent Geodatabase is stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 and the replicated child is stored in SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

Comment: I cross-posted this on the ESRI [support forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/63975-__ATTACH-tables-break-replication-in-ArcGIS-10?p=221551#post221551).  I got a reply from an ESRI employee, but it did not directly address my problem.